# Compose TextField: placing cursor on text removes LineThrough TextDecoration

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, textfield, rich-text-editor, android-compose-textfield

I'm using a `TextField` or `BasicTextField` in compose and setting strikethrough span on the text using:

`SpanStyle(textDecoration = TextDecoration.LineThrough)`

It renders strikethrough on the text as expected. However, when I place the cursor on it, the strikethrough disappears and the text is underlined instead. Underlining is the default behavior I think whenever the cursor is placed on the text so I think that's fine.

[image]

[image]

But how do I get strikethrough to show when the cursor is positioned on the text?

This doesn't happen on view-based `EditText` or `AppCompatEditText`.

Comment: Checkout https://codingwithrashid.com/how-to-add-strikethrough-text-in-android-jetpack-compose/ 
Might be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this,

```
SpanStyle(textDecoration = TextDecoration.LineThrough, 
              underline = TextDecoration(
                  color = Color.Red,
                  thickness = 1.dp,
                  width = TextDecoration.Width.Intrinsic
              )
    )
```

This will apply a red underline with a thickness of 1dp when the cursor is placed on the text. You can adjust the values to fit your desired styling.

Alternatively, you can also disable the underline altogether by setting the underline to TextDecoration.None.

**scss**

```
SpanStyle(textDecoration = TextDecoration.LineThrough, 
          underline = TextDecoration.None
)
```

This will prevent any underline from appearing when the cursor is placed on the text.

Answer (score -1):

Try setting paint flags for editText

```
editText.paintFlags = Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
```

remove set

```
editText.paintFlags = Paint.CURSOR_AFTER
```